# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and ARKit: is it possible to use them together?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, avcapturesession, arkit, avcapturedevice

I've found that using an `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` camera overlay, the quality of the camera image shown is quite better than when using an `ARSKView`. I need to use `ARKit` and display some `SKNodes` according to the camera ouput, so I guess that using `ARSKView` and running its session is mandatory. On the other hand, it seems that for the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` it is needed to set an `AVCaptureSession` session instead.

Is it possible to get the camera output from the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` and still being able to display AR elemnts by using `ARKit`? Otherwise, is there anyway to improve the quality of the camera output when using `ARSKView`? I've its related session set up like this:

```
if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.isSupported {
  let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
  skView.session.run(configuration)
}
```